# Convert collection to key value collection

Tags: php, laravel, dictionary, collections, key-value

I have the following collection:

```
$configuration = DB::table('configuration')->get();

Illuminate\Support\Collection {#562 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => {#1447 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "assign_device_email_addresses"
      +"configuration_value": "mobiles@example.com|accountspayable@example.com"
    }
    1 => {#1357 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "helpdesk_platform_url"
      +"configuration_value": "https://clouddesk.com/app/itdesk/ui/requests/{helpdeskurl}/details"
    }
    2 => {#1446 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "mail_encryption"
      +"configuration_value": "tls"
    }
    3 => {#563 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "mail_host"
      +"configuration_value": "exampleserver.example.com"
    }
    4 => {#1292 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "mail_password"
      +"configuration_value": "encrypted_password"
    }
    5 => {#1291 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "mail_port"
      +"configuration_value": "465"
    }
    6 => {#885 ▼
      +"configuration_name": "mail_username"
      +"configuration_value": "mobiles"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this structure I can only access each item via the following statements:

```
  $configuration[0]->configuration_name
  $configuration[0]->configuration_value
  $configuration[1]->configuration_name
  $configuration[1]->configuration_value
etc.
```

I want to be able to access it via:

```
  $configuration->assign_device_email returning "mobiles@example.com|accountspayable@example.com".
  $configuration->mail_host returning "exampleserver.example.com".
etc.
```

How can I can convert this collection so that I can access each property value via it's configuration_name?

I have tried the below which got me closer, but I still can't access it via statements like: $configuration->mail_port etc.

```
$configuration2 = DB::table('configuration')->get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function($configuration2){
            return [$configuration2->configuration_name => $configuration2->configuration_value]; 
    });
```

I think this fails as the above statement still returns an array:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1500 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    "assign_device_email_addresses" => "mobiles@example.com|accountspayable@example.com"
    "helpdesk_platform_url" => "https://clouddesk.com/app/itdesk/ui/requests/{helpdeskurl}/details"
    "mail_encryption" => "tls"
    "mail_host" => "exampleserver.example.com"
    "mail_password" => "encrypted_password"
    "mail_port" => "465"
    "mail_username" => "mobiles"
  ]
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? I feel like I am getting closer with it, but collections confuse me a bit.

I think I am essentially after something like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1507 ▼
    +"assign_device_email_addresses" : "mobiles@example.com"
    +"helpdesk_platform_url" : "https://cloudesk.com/app/itdesk/ui/requests/{helpdeskurl}/details"
    +"mail_encryption" : "tls"
    +"mail_host" : "emailhost@example.com"
    +"mail_password" : "encrypted_password"
    +"mail_port" : "465"
    +"mail_username" : "mobiles"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Arr` helper to map in key value:

```
$configuration = DB::table('configuration')->get();
$configuration =  Arr::pluck($configuration, 'configuration_value','configuration_name');
```

also, add below line to import class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately this is still returning as an array. When doing        dd($configuration->helpdesk_platform_url) for example I receive the error: Attempt to read property "helpdesk_platform_url" on array.

Comment: you have to check by configuration['helpdesk_platform_url']

Comment: Thanks! This is working great! I feel really stupid now. I had for some reason forgotten what an associative array is as I am so used to the object (->) operator used for Laravel collections. I am still curious if it's possible to map a collection in the way referenced in my question, but this has largely solved my problem so thank you.